# What is the difference between microsoft visual studio scrum 2.0 vs MSF for Agile Software Development 6.0

Tags: tfs, scrum, tfs-process-template, ms-solution-framework

What is the difference between Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2.0 vs MSF for Agile Software Development 6.0.

I am looking to get feedback on what is the best template to use for Visual Studio and TFS for agile development. I was mostly wondering if anyone can tell me the difference between the two latest templates in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The scrum template has been created specifically to follow the scrum process and terminology as closely as possible and was built as a collaborative effort between Microsoft and scrum.org.

The MSF for agile template was originally created as a generic process template for agile development.

If you will be doing Scrum, which at the moment is the most common agile process, then the scrum process template is the most logical choice.

If you want to follow another agile process, then MSF for agile might be a better fit, since it should be usable in most agile processes. The naming might not completely match, but the process can probably be mapped to it.

Differences are explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/work/guidance/choose-process

Comment: Great link -- explains the work item types that you get

Answer (score 0):

Other explanations came summaries into one picture

[image]

Read at https://nkdagility.com/agile-vs-scrum-process-templates-team-foundation-server/

In short:

In SCRUM bugs go to product log, but not in Agile.