# process template difference in tfs 2013

Tags: tfs, agile-processes

In TFS 2013 there are 3 available templates.

Microsoft Visual Studio Scrum 2013

MSF for Agile Software Development 2013

MSF for CMMI Process Improvement 2013

Is there any significant difference using the Scrum template instead of MSF for Agile Software Development 2013?

In MSF for Agile Software Development 2013 there is iteration configuration possibility, but release and sprints are absent, while in Scrum there are both iterations and sprints.

Besides this, is there any other serious differences?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between microsoft visual studio scrum 2.0 vs MSF for Agile Software Development 6.0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14779250/what-is-the-difference-between-microsoft-visual-studio-scrum-2-0-vs-msf-for-agil)

Comment: See [`Work with team project artifacts, choose a process template`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400752.aspx) on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

The differences between scrum and agile are for the most part the same cmmi is a more complex process often used in government projects that require more process steps.

For a detailed breakdown of each process template see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms400752.aspx

With the power tools for tfs it is possible to edit the template that has been to selected to either customize existing work items or create new ones.